# Function is calling before service loaded

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, events

I am using blazeDS in my web application. I am facing issue with Java and flex.

I have used function to load service in creation complete event of application. And I need to get value in combo box and do some manipulation. But my function which will trace the value, is being called before service is loading. for that reason function is not returning any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can overcome by doing following changes

1) call webservice in [Application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html) initizlize event

2) Call your method in [ResultEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/ResultEvent.html) triggers on result of Webservice
or

3) IF Still you face same issue you can call it using [callLater()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_12.html)

or

4)IF callLater() wont work to, then you can use Event [collectionchange](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#event%3acollectionChange) of [ListCollectionView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#event%3acollectionChange) a Parent Class of [ArrayCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html), [XMLListCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html)

I personaly recommend DO Steps 1 and 4 Only.

Hopes that helps